# trouble with joining two tables correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with car mileage data, the selection of that table looks like this:

[image]

It gives per car, per month the existing value. The problem I have now is that I need it to have a car row for each month. Now it only shows a car row if the car has a mileage in that said month. I want it so that a car will have a row for each month, with current data or just NULL values.

To do this I have made a list with a car ID per month, here is the code for that and what it looks like.

```
,   carMonthList as (
SELECT
    M.MonthDate
,   difflist.FK_CarID as fkc
FROM
    carMKcombiDiffList as difflist cross join
    MonthList M 
)
```

A small problem that he makes (amount of months) times a row for a car for a month.

[image]

Then I try to combine the the table with the car data and the table with the car per month data using a UNION. Here is the code and example result for that:

```
,   fullList as (
SELECT
    CMlist.MonthDate
,   CMlist.fkc as CarID
,   NULL as beginMonth
,   NULL as KM
,   NULL as diff
,   NULL as CO2
FROM 
    carMonthList as CMlist

UNION

SELECT
    diffList.beginMonth
,   diffList.FK_CarID as CarID
,   diffList.beginMonth
,   diffList.KM
,   diffList.diff
,   diffList.CO2
FROM
    carMKcombiDiffList as diffList
)
```

The problem here is that for a month where there does exist data, he makes two rows. You can see this at the month 05, it has two rows, one for each side of the union. I can't filter them out by checking the two dates, as it would delete all the empty ones. How can/ should I fix this whilst keeping the rows for each month with NULL values for the car data? 
[image]

Comment: I'll shorten the data set and update the pics for 1 car

Comment: Easiest and safest way is to create months table, cross join it to cars table and left join your car monthly data to these tables - this way you have record for each car and each month available.

Comment: I did this but then I did not have a month row for each month per car. Only when there was car data for that month

Comment: Sounds like you did an inner join, instead of a outer join,

Comment: i'll remake my old code and test it again, if it fails I'll report back.

Comment: I tried this, the problem here is that for the rows where there should be no mileage data, he copies whatever mileage he has for that car. So for the car in the example it is 6 times a 0 while it should be one 0 and 5 times NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Arvo's suggestion

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0dfa4/1) working example